# Select statement in php function

Tags: php, mysql, function, select

I am attempting to create a function that will take a query in mysql and output it with mysql_fetch_assoc.

The issue is when I return the output inside the loop it only outputs the first field. Likewise, if I return the output outside of the loop I only get the last value.

Is there anyway to get around this?

Here is the main page:

```
<?php
$dbhost = "localhost";
$dbuser = "widget_cms";
$dbpass = "cjclone123";
$dbdata = "widget_corp";
$connection = mysqli_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass, $dbdata);

if(mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    die("database connection failed: " .
        mysqli_connect_error() .
            " (" . mysqli_connect_errno() . ")"
    );
} else {
    echo "success!";
} 

Insert_Line_Into_subjects();

    $table = "subjects";

    $result = Output_Table($table);

    var_dump($result);

    echo (Display_Table($result));

    mysqli_free_result($result); 


?>  
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"
   "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">

<html lang="en">
 <head>
  <title>phpMysql</title>
 </head>
 <body>

    <ul>
     <form action="phpMysql.php" method="post">
     Menu Name: <input type="text" name="menuName" value=""><br>
     Position: <input type="text" name="pos" value=""><br>
     Visibility: <input type="text" name="vis" value=""><br>
     <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Create account"><br>
     </form>
    </ul> 

 </body>
</html>

<?php mysqli_close($connection); ?>
```

Here are all the functions that I used:

```
function Insert_Line_Into_subjects(){

if (isset($_POST["submit"])) {
    global $connection; 

    $menu_name = ($_POST["menuName"]);
    $position = ($_POST["pos"]);
    $visibility = ($_POST["vis"]);

    $query1 = "INSERT INTO subjects ";
    $query1 .= "(menu_name, position, visible) ";
    $query1 .= "VALUES ('$menu_name', '$position', '$visibility')";
    $result = mysqli_query($connection, $query1);
    Check_SQL_Execution($result);
    return $result;
    }
}

    function Check_SQL_Execution($result) {
        global $connection;

    if (!$result) {
        die("<br>Database query failed: " . mysqli_error($connection));
    }
    }

    function Output_Table ($table) {
    global $connection; 

    $query1 = "SELECT * ";
    $query1 .= "FROM {$table}" ;
    $result1 = mysqli_query($connection, $query1);
    Check_SQL_Execution($result1);
    return $result1; 

}

    function Display_Table($result) {

        //if (isset($_POST["submit"])){
        $output = '';

        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        $output = $row["menu_name"];
        $output .= " ("; 
        $output .= $row["id"];
        $output .= ")";
    }
    return $output;
 }
```

What did I do wrong? Thanks!

Comment: The `return` line should be _outside_ the loop.

Comment: what is you expected output?

Comment: I expected the entire table to output. Each menu name and id.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
function Display_Table($result) {
    $output = '';
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        $output .= $row["menu_name"];
        $output .= " ("; 
        $output .= $row["id"];
        $output .= ")";
    }
    return $output;
}
```

Comment: I tried this and it only outputted the last value in the table.

Comment: show me the proof. show me full fragment of your code (where and how you use this function), query and sample of data you execute your query against

Comment: @zach, the subtle difference here with Alex's snippet is that $output is appended to on each loop, whereas you were clobbering it each time.

Comment: That was it! Thank you.